Ripple CI: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in '/tmp/scope-fs'
I am trying to run Ripple CI with my custom webpack transformer for preview mode.
Ripple CI logs
✖ (9/11) env: bitdev.general/envs/bit-env@1.0.13, task "teambit.preview/preview:GenerateEnvTemplate" has failed in 4s
- (10/11) [Preview: GeneratePreview] Bundling components for preview
  running Webpack bundler (total: 1)
- running Webpack bundler (1/1)   running on 1 components
✔ running Webpack bundler. Succeeded in 2s
✔ (10/11) [Preview: GeneratePreview] Completed successfully in 4s
- (11/11) [Preview: PreBundlePreview]
✔ (11/11) [Preview: PreBundlePreview] Completed successfully in 196μs
✔ running tasks. Succeeded in 54s
  running post-build for all tasks 
✔ running post-build for all tasks. Succeeded in 9ms
✖ Running build pipeline using 1 environment(s), total 11 tasks. Failed in 54s
- start processing the exported data
- all objects were persisted successfully!
The following errors were found while running the build pipeline
Failed task 1: "teambit.preview/preview:GenerateEnvTemplate" of env "bitdev.general/envs/bit-env@1.0.13"
component: ***/flw-react@c415bf94395ab61346523ee785aaccef88ad1b83
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in '/tmp/scope-fs'
Found 1 errors in 1 components

Local environment

bvm@1.0.7
bit@1.8.20
node@20.14.0
pnpm@9.2.0

Custom react-env
┌──────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ id               │ ***                                                                      [modified]                      │
├──────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ scope            │ ***                                                                                                      │
├──────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ name             │ envs/flw-react                                                                                           │
├──────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ env              │ bitdev.general/envs/bit-env@1.0.13                                                                       │
├──────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ package name     │ ***.flw-react                                                                                            │
├──────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ deprecated       │ false                                                                                                    │
├──────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ forking          │ origin: frontend.shadcn-ui/shadcn-ui-env@0.0.24                                                          │
├──────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ main file        │ index.ts                                                                                                 │
├──────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ files            │ env.jsonc                                                                                                │
│                  │ flw-react.bit-env.ts                                                                                     │
│                  │ flw-react.docs.mdx                                                                                       │
│                  │ index.ts                                                                                                 │
│                  │ config/eslint.config.cjs                                                                                 │
│                  │ config/postcss.config.cjs                                                                                │
│                  │ config/prettier.config.cjs                                                                               │
│                  │ config/tailwind.config.ts                                                                                │
│                  │ config/tsconfig.base.json                                                                                │
│                  │ config/vitest.config.mjs                                                                                 │
│                  │ config/vitest.setup.mjs                                                                                  │
│                  │ config/webpack.config.ts                                                                                 │
│                  │ preview/mounter.tsx                                                                                      │
│                  │ types/env.d.ts                                                                                           │
├──────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ dev files        │ flw-react.docs.mdx (teambit.docs/docs)                                                                   │
├──────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ aspects          │ bitdev.general/envs/bit-env@1.0.13                                                                       │
│                  │ teambit.component/dev-files                                                                              │
│                  │ teambit.component/forking                                                                                │
│                  │ teambit.compositions/compositions                                                                        │
│                  │ teambit.dependencies/dependency-resolver                                                                 │
│                  │ teambit.docs/docs                                                                                        │
│                  │ teambit.envs/envs                                                                                        │
│                  │ teambit.harmony/application                                                                              │
│                  │ teambit.pipelines/builder                                                                                │
│                  │ teambit.pkg/pkg                                                                                          │
│                  │ teambit.preview/preview                                                                                  │
│                  │ teambit.semantics/schema                                                                                 │
├──────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ dependencies     │ @apollo/client@^3.8.8----------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ @mdx-js/mdx@^1.6.22------------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ @mdx-js/react@1.6.22------------------------------------------------------------------------ (package)   │
│                  │ @radix-ui/react-icons@^1.3.0---------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ @teambit/mdx.ui.mdx-scope-context@1.0.7----------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ @testing-library/dom@10.4.0----------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ @testing-library/jest-dom@6.4.8------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ @testing-library/react@^16.0.0-------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ @types/eslint@8.56.0------------------------------------------------------------------------ (package)   │
│                  │ @types/find-root@^1.1.4--------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ @types/jest@^29.2.2------------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ @types/node@20.12.10------------------------------------------------------------------------ (package)   │
│                  │ @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@6.19.1----------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ @typescript-eslint/parser@6.19.1------------------------------------------------------------ (package)   │
│                  │ @vitest/coverage-v8@^2.0.4------------------------------------------------------------------ (package)   │
│                  │ autoprefixer@^10.4.20----------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ @bitdev/react.eslint.eslint-config-bit-react@1.1.2------------------------------------------ (component) │
│                  │ @bitdev/react.generators.react-templates@2.1.0---------------------------------------------- (component) │
│                  │ @bitdev/react.react-env@2.1.2--------------------------------------------------------------- (component) │
│                  │ browserslist@4.23.0------------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ css-loader@^7.1.2--------------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ eslint@8.56.0------------------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ eslint-config-prettier@^9.1.0--------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ eslint-plugin-import@2.29.1----------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ eslint-plugin-jest@27.6.3------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@6.8.0---------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ eslint-plugin-mdx@3.1.5--------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ eslint-plugin-react@7.33.2------------------------------------------------------------------ (package)   │
│                  │ eslint-plugin-react-hooks@4.6.0------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ eslint-plugin-tailwindcss@^3.17.0----------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ find-root@^1.1.0---------------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ @frontend/nextjs.templates.generators@0.4.6------------------------------------------------- (component) │
│                  │ graphql@^16.8.1----------------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ jsdom@^24.0.0------------------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ lucide-react@^0.377.0----------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ pino-pretty@4.5.0--------------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ postcss-flexbugs-fixes@^5.0.2--------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ postcss-loader@^8.1.1----------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ postcss-preset-env@^10.0.3------------------------------------------------------------------ (package)   │
│                  │ react@^18.0.0------------------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ react-dom@^18.0.0--------------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ react-router-dom@^6.26.0-------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ sass@^1.69.5-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ style-loader@^4.0.0------------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ tailwindcss@^3.4.12------------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ tailwindcss-animate@^1.0.7------------------------------------------------------------------ (package)   │
│                  │ @teambit/defender.eslint-linter@1.0.39------------------------------------------------------ (component) │
│                  │ @teambit/defender.prettier-formatter@1.0.19------------------------------------------------- (component) │
│                  │ @teambit/mdx.ui.mdx-scope-context@1.0.7----------------------------------------------------- (component) │
│                  │ @teambit/preview.react-preview@1.0.44------------------------------------------------------- (component) │
│                  │ @teambit/react.mounter@1.0.6---------------------------------------------------------------- (component) │
│                  │ @teambit/toolbox.performance.v8-cache@0.0.33------------------------------------------------ (component) │
│                  │ @teambit/typescript.typescript-compiler@2.0.44---------------------------------------------- (component) │
│                  │ @teambit/vite.vitest-tester@0.2.1----------------------------------------------------------- (component) │
│                  │ typescript@^5.6.2--------------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ vite@^5.3.5--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ vitest@^2.0.4------------------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
│                  │ webpack@^5.88.2----------------------------------------------------------------------------- (package)   │
├──────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ dev dependencies │ @types/react@^18.3.5---------------- (package)                                                           │
│                  │ @bitdev/general.envs.bit-env@1.0.13- (component)                                                         │
└──────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

webpack.config.ts
import { createRequire } from 'node:module';

import type { WebpackConfigMutator } from '@teambit/webpack';

const cjsRequire = createRequire(import.meta.url);

export const webpackTransformer = (
    configMutator: WebpackConfigMutator
): WebpackConfigMutator => {
    const postcssConfig = cjsRequire.resolve('./postcss.config.cjs');

    // add new rule for tailwind
    configMutator.addModuleRule({
        test: /\.tailwind\.css$/,
        include: [/globals\.tailwind\.css/],
        use: [
            'style-loader',
            {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true,
                    importLoaders: 1,
                },
            },
            {
                loader: 'postcss-loader',
                options: {
                    postcssOptions: {
                        config: postcssConfig,
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    });

    return configMutator;
};

I add style-loader also into env.jsonc so I'm expecting that this package will be part of the capsule. But Ripple CI can't find it.

There's already a tailwind transformer you can bring as a dependency for adding TW to Bit. You can find it here, alongside other TW-Bit related plugins - https://bit.cloud/frontend/tailwind

Thanks for the answer, but I need to add custom postcss plugin just for this specific file. So I can't use it globally for all .css files. But I think I found a way, I just need to resolve path for the loaders like this: cjsRequire.resolve('style-loader')
Some how RippleCI can't find those modules, I guess the folder structure is different from local

if you need to add any loader, ensure it is also mentioned in env.jsonc, as this is how you place dependencies that are needed for your tooling / development environment
